# FileExplorer - Error when selecting directory file xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a file explorer in my app.The user will be exporting some file on the click of a button.When the button is clicked,it launches the file explorer.I would like them to choose a destination folder where they'll export this file.This is how i would like it to work:

1.If the parent directory is the sdCard,they can opt to just save it here.If not,the sd card should display any sub directories e.d Downloads/My Documents etc and they can select any of these folders.This should allow them to go to any lower levels folders they like or navigate back and choose a higher one.

My challenge is,when they click on a folder for now,it displays sub directories.But if the sub directory itself has no child directories,clicking on it gives blank screen.I also don't know how to select my desired folder.e.g,if i want to select just the sd card folder without looking into it.

Here's what i have so far:

```
public override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {

        try{

            var folderSystemInfo = _adapter.GetItem(position);

            //Check if the directory has any sub directories

            if(folderSystemInfo.IsDirectory())
            {
                if(folderSystemInfo.GetDirectories() == null)
                {

                    // Do something with the file.  In this case we just pop some toast.
                    Log.Verbose("FileListFragment", "The file {0} was clicked.", folderSystemInfo.FullName);
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "You selected the Folder " + folderSystemInfo.FullName, ToastLength.Short).Show();

                    OnFileClick (folderSystemInfo);





                }else{

                    // Dig into this directory, and display it's contents-
                    RefreshFoldersList(folderSystemInfo.FullName); 

                }


            }

}catch(Exception ex)
        {


        }

        base.OnListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


    }


public void RefreshFoldersList(string directory)
    {


        IList<DirectoryInfo> visibleThings = new List<DirectoryInfo>();

        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);



        try
        {
            foreach (var item in dir.GetDirectories().Where(item => item.IsVisible()))
            {

                visibleThings.Add(item);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("FileListFragment", "Couldn't access the directory " + _directory.FullName + "; " + ex);
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Problem retrieving contents of " + directory, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return;
        }

        _directory = dir;

        _adapter.AddDirectoryContents(visibleThings);

        // If we don't do this, then the ListView will not update itself when the data set 
        // in the adapter changes. It will appear to the user that nothing has happened.
        ListView.RefreshDrawableState();

        Log.Verbose("FileListFragment", "Displaying the contents of directory {0}.", directory);
    }
```

Comment: I did something before and this helped me https://github.com/mikescandy/FilePicker

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for and more! I was stuck on implementing the backward navigation of the files and the file mode enum just solved all my problems!Thank you so much!I am very grateful :)